# Crop Data from SQLite database in python

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I get following Data from the server:

```
[('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',)]
```

I want to crop it so that I only got the number without the quotes.
I used following code to do so :

```
     for row in rows:
        print(row)
        test = re.match("'[^']*'", row)
        listbox.insert(END, rows)
```

but if i do so I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fabiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/coding/Python/Hello World/FileWriter.py", line 119, in retrieveNotes
    select_all_tasks(conn)
  File "C:/coding/Python/Hello World/FileWriter.py", line 91, in select_all_tasks
    test = re.match("'[^']*'", row)
  File "C:\Users\fabiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 189, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Wait, how does SQLite factor into this?

Comment: Maybe `test = re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", str(row))` and then `listbox.insert(END, test)`?

Comment: @AKX I have no idea thats the stuff i get

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works u can mark it as answer thx a lot

Comment: How is this "getting the number without the quotes"?

Answer (score 0):

You may extract all substrings in between single quotes using `re.findall`, not `re.match`, passing the `str(row)` value as the input (since `row` does not seem to be of `string` type):

```
test = re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", str(row))
```

Then you need to add the found matches to your listbox, not `rows`:

```
listbox.insert(END, test)
```